# Azure DevOps - iteration change

Tags: azure-devops, iteration

I have two teams assigned to one project.
Currently, they're working using the same iterations.
Starting from new iteration I want to change this setting. One team (A) will work using iterations 2 weeks long, the other (B) 3 weeks long.
I am looking for answers to the following questions:

- will team B board be cleared (I'm fine with that, just want to be 'ready' for that)?
- will team A board be affected by the change of team B settings?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your scenario & questions correctly, going into the new sprint (iteration) you would like to split your team's iteration duration.  Team A to 2 week iterations and Team B to 3 week long iterations.

If that's correct, then changing your team's iteration duration shouldn't have an affect on the boards, meaning backlog and sprint boards.  You may want to look at adjusting your team member's capacity.  Also make sure when you create new iterations to add them to your team configurations, and look at what your teams' default iteration is.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , creating a new iteration for the team will not clear the previous team board.
And the change of team B will not affect team A.

You can switch iterations of different periods of the team in Spirits.

[image]